# Joining with dual table (number range)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to join dual table with two others tables containing data with same key

Here's the structure ;

My first column would be like:

```
(with bnd as (select 1 lo, 100 hi from dual)
select (select lo from bnd) - 1 + level r
from dual
```

Which will result in range of integers

```
Id r
1| 1
2| 2
3| 3
4| 4
```

Then I want to join it with two tables in which every rows contains number from 1 to 100( each number can exist only in one of them)

A

```
Id r  Type
1| 1  Cat
2| 3  Dog
3| 9  Cat
```

B

```
Id r  Type
1| 2  Woman
2| 6  Man
3| 8  Woman
```

The final result should show "r" and Type from 2 tables, or null if r can't be found (sort by r Ascending) :

```
Id r  Type
1|1  Cat
2|2  Woman
3|3  Dog
4|4  Null
```

Any ideas on that? I was always using Management Studio so i don't have any experience with that dual, thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more typical way to generate numbers is:

```
with bounds as (
      select 1 as lo, 4 as hi from dual
     ),
     n as (
      select level + lo - 1 as lvl
      from bounds
      connect by level + lo - 1 <= hi
     )
select *
from n;
```

Then to do what you want, you can use `left joins`:

```
with bounds as (
      select 1 as lo, 4 as hi from dual
     ),
     n as (
      select level + lo - 1 as r
      from bounds
      connect by level + lo - 1 <= hi
     )
select n.r, coalesce(a.type, b.type)
from n left join
     a
     on n.t = a.r left join
     b
     on n.r = b.r
```